# C#: A simple way to bring One-line-XML-files to human readable multi line

Tags: c#, xml

I'm looking for a simply way to bring a xml-File with one line without line feeds to a good structured human readable version in C#. Is there any Implementation already in System.XML or a tiny open source framework or a best practice for implementing it?

ex. transform this XML-String:

```
<Root><Node id="1"><Childnode>Text</Childnode></Node><Node id="2">Text<Kid name="jack" /></Node></Root>
```

to

```
<Root>
  <Node id="1">
    <Childnode>
      Text
    </Childnode>
  </Node>
  <Node id="2">
    Text
    <Kid name="jack" />
  </Node>
</Root>
```

Answer (score 8):

If you have .NET 3.5:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(filename);
document.Save(filename);
```

This will indent automatically. Note that it won't do quite as your question asked, because you're only indenting *some* of the nodes. That's going to be trickier.

If you're stuck with .NET 2.0, here's Craig's method rejigged and changed to use files instead of strings:

```
public static void FormatXmlString(string inputFile, string outputFile)
{
    XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
    document.Load(inputFile);
    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    settings.Indent = true;
    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(outputFile, settings))
    {
        document.WriteTo(writer);
    }
}
```

With C# 3 the `XmlWriterSettings` but could just be:

```
new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true }
```

which could be embedded in the call to `XmlWriter.Create`, but if you're using .NET 2.0 you *probably* can't use C# 3.

EDIT: If the input filename part causes a problem, you can use:

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
using (Stream stream = File.OpenRead(inputFile))
{
    document.Load(stream);
}
```

Comment: the difference between the 3.5 version and the 2.0 version is that 3.5. is a filename to filename solution and 2.0 a string to string solution. How would be a filename to filename solution in 2.0?

Comment: Create an XmlWriter that writes to a file instead: XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(filename, settings).

Comment: Has probably nothing to do with your code. I always get a WebException by document.Load(inputFile) because of missing proxy authentication, but the file is on the local filesystem...

Comment: You could pass in a stream instead. Odd that it tried to load it as a web request even though it presumably didn't start with http:// though :(

Comment: (I've added an extra bit if you want to change that part of things.)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a handy "FormatXML" class that I wrote for just this purpose:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;

public static class FormatXML
{
    public static string FormatXMLString(string sUnformattedXML)
    {
        XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
        xd.LoadXml(sUnformattedXML);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
        XmlTextWriter xtw = null;
        try
        {
            xtw = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
            xtw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            xd.WriteTo(xtw);
        }
        finally
        {
            if(xtw!=null)
                xtw.Close();
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: xtw pattern looks overcomplicated, using will be better.

Comment: Not only would a using statement be better, but you can use XmlWriter.Create(sb) to avoid bothering with the StringWriter too.

Comment: @arbiter, @JonSkeet - You guys are correct in that this code could well be optimized and probably doesn't represent a "perfect" implementation of the mechanism, however, I've used the above code (as-is) in a sample web-service client application that I recently wrote in work and it's worked well for me!  By all means, improve it!  That's what SO is all about after all!  :)

Comment: It's not a matter of optimisation, just making the code clearer.

Comment: @JonSkeet - I know what you're saying, Jon, but I do consider it a kind of optimization since you have removed the need to instantiate a StringWriter object at least.  That'll save a small amount of memory overhead if nothing else!  :)  Plus, it *does* make the code clearer as you say.

Answer (score 3):

If you have got Visual Studio:

Create a new XML file and just paste your code. It will re-format it automatically.

Comment: that wasn't what I was asking for. I asked for ''implementing'' it.