# How to add style information to single line xml file

Tags: c#, xml

For our swimming database we have written an nice importer that has worked for a couple of years now. However, the source of the times (xml file per meet) has changed and now the importer doesn't work anymore.

The problem is that the new xml files have all the data on 1 line instead of a normal tree-like stucture.
When i open the xml file in a browser it says 'This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.'

Now before anyone says this can be ignored, it can't in our program.
So i am looking for a way to add this style information to the xml file via C#.
Anyone got any ideas how to do it or where to look ?

BTW, those who have seen this message before and want to add the style information to a single file, check out http://citrixblogger.org/2010/08/13/one-line-xml-files/
(This works great for a few files, but to do about 100 by hand each week, including saving the file afterwards etc, is not a real option for me).

Comment: Can you post an example of previously working XML and the new XML?  Also, how are the XML files generated?

Comment: It may depend on what tool you use to render the xml. For instance if the xml file contains the following processing instruction `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="stylesheet.xsl"?>` Internet Explorer will use stylesheet.xsl to transform the xml and render the ouptput. Obviously you need to have the stylesheet.xsl.

Comment: Hope this helps (search is a wonderful thing). 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068473/c-a-simple-way-to-bring-one-line-xml-files-to-human-readable-multi-line

Comment: JuStDaN : thank you very much, the link you posted held the solution: just open the file and save it again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that was needed was:

```
xmlDoc.Save(fileName);
```

Thank you JuStDaN.